# How to fix this BADSIG issue?

Tags: apt

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 793FEB8BB69735B2 Vivaldi Package Composer KEY06 <packager@vivaldi.com>
E: The repository 'http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: If you are trying to install the Vivaldi web browser, you could also go to [their download page](https://vivaldi.com/download/), and and use the dropdown to select the correct architecture (probobly 64bit, but maybe not). Download the correct version, and install it with [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/1438484).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download their GPG key and add it to the system by using command below:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
```

then update package lists again by `sudo apt-get update` as usual.

Comment: But it still says W: GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 793FEB8BB69735B2 Vivaldi Package Composer KEY06 <packager@vivaldi.com>
E: The repository 'http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Then retry by `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 
 793FEB8BB69735B2` .